# Git difftool submodules

Tags: git, beyondcompare, vimdiff, difftool

I'm thinking about using submodules in a way that they aren't really meant for but my goal is to streamline some things for the devs. I've got a project that is basically made up of only submodules - 4 of them. It is important that they are independent of one another or I would just make one big repo. From the parent repo, I can see the diff for all submodules at once by doing `git diff --submodule=diff`.

But what I really want is the equivalent of `git difftool -d` but for all submodules at once. Theoretically difftool should work with the `--submodule=diff` flag (since `git difftool` has all the same options as diff) but it doesn't. Ideas?